# Rails controller parameters are different from sending parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Rails parameters are different actual sending parameters

**Parameters sending from the postman:**

```
{
"first_name": "Arun",
"last_name": "Deepak",
"email": "arun.deepak@abc.com",
"password": "Abc@123",
"confirm_pasword": "Abc@123",
"user_type": "seller"
}
```

**Params in controller:**

```
{
"first_name"=>"Arun", "last_name"=>"Deepak",
"email"=>"arun.deepak@abc.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_pasword"=>"Abc@123",
"user_type"=>"seller",
"user"=>{"email"=>"arun.deepak@abc.com", "user_type"=>"seller"}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
def create
  @user = User.create!(user_params)
  render json: @user
end
...
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_type, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

**Rails routes:**

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

Here, How is the parameter changing in the controller?

I know I'm sending the wrong parameters but How are user_params accepting the wrong parameters?

How the request parameters have been modified?

Answer (score 1):

The params don't get changed in the controllers. Maybe you are trying to send `first_name` and `last_name` as user params. And it is giving you an error during user creation. That's because your `user_params` method is only returning params that are under the user, using this `params.require(:user)`.

```
Parameters: {
  "user": {
    "email": "arun.deepak@abc.com",
    "user_type": "seller",
    "first_name": "Arun",
    "last_name": "Deepak",
    "password": "[FILTERED]",
    "confirm_pasword": "Abc@123"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sending the wrong parameters but why it's allowing? and How it's modified?

Comment: If you’re using Postman then you can easily add params like `user[email]` or `user[first_name]`

Comment: I'm saying I'm sending the wrong params but the system is accepting how it's possible?

Comment: I don't know what’s actually happening in your project ‍♂️